# GDPR and Guests information

Tags: magento2, gdpr

In accordance with GDPR, we need to allow our customers (Guests or Not) the ability to access the information we hold about them on file. Obviously, Registered Customers can access their information via the Account after logging in.

However, Guest customers (AKA Not logged in) would have to obtain this information through the Store (e.g. admin, customer service, etc...).

On the backend `Customers` > `All Customers` lists registered customers. However, we hold just as much information for Guests within Magento but not accessible from this location.

So, is there an out-the-box solution to search for Guest Customers information within Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Under GDPR law, individuals will have the full right to ask for their personal data and this needs to be a full copy of the data which could be sitting under several tables in your Magento database. Here is the list of Magento tables where personal data could be stored

- Quote
- Quote Address
- Order
- Order Address
- Customer
- Customer Address
- Newsletter

You need to make sure you have the provision to extract this data out of your database when requested within 30 days of the request and this should be free of charge, you can't ask for fee especially when this is the first time request by the customer.

Magento out of the box, you can't even give all the information to your customers even if they are registered. You need to build a solution which can extract all the personal information which are sitting in the above mention tables.

There are several extensions available which can help you achieve this if you are no willing to build or pay your developer to build extract customer data feature.

Apart from providing access data, I would highly recommend you to read [GDPR checklist](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-gdpr-compliance.html), this will give you everything you need to know about GDPR and Magento

Would highly recommend to use the following extensions -:

[GDPR Magento 1](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento1-gdpr-compliance.html)

[GDPR Magento 2](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-gdpr-compliance.html)